# No such file or directory while web scrapping altough the folder does exist

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, request

i want to scrape all the .csv files from the url list in my code like this

```
os.makedirs("Project Data ISPU SPKU DKI JAKARTA 2010 - 2021", exist_ok=True)

change_directory = r"C:\Users\EVOSYS\Documents\PROJECT-ISPU-DKI-JAKARTA-main\Project Data ISPU SPKU DKI JAKARTA 2010 - 2021"

os.chdir(change_directory)
print("Current Working directory has been changed to :", os.getcwd())

URLS = [
        'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2020',
        'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2021',
        'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/data-indeks-standar-pencemar-udara-ispu-di-provinsi-dki-jakarta-tahun-2019'
       ]


for url in URLS:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    folder = url.split("/")[-1]
    os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)

    for a in soup.select('a[href$=".csv"]'):
        file_name = a["href"].split("/")[-1]
        
        path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)

        print(
            "Downloading {} ...".format(path),
            end=" ",)
        
        with open(path, "wb") as f_out:
            f_out.write(requests.get(a["href"]).content)
        print("OK.")
```

but for the 2019 url it gives an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data-indeks-standar-pencemar-udara-ispu-di-provinsi-dki-jakarta-tahun-2019\\Indeks-Standar-Pencemar-Udara-di-Provinsi-DKI-Jakarta-Bulan-Januari-Tahun-2019.csv'
```

i already check that the folder for 2019 data does exist but it still showing an error that the folder is not exist, all the url using the sam tag (href) to get the .csv files

Comment: works fine on my end, I can not reproduce your error. Only thing I can think of is to make sure you are running from current working directory.

Comment: i already set the current working directory, but it keeps showing error for 2019 link, the other link is working just fine

Comment: Again, works fine on my end and completes with no error. Can;t reproduce it, so not much I can do to help debug. What OS are you working in? is it Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: sorry, maybe my explanation is not complete, so im creating a new folder, `os.makedirs("Project Data ISPU SPKU DKI JAKARTA 2010 - 2021", exist_ok=True)` so all the downloaded file is stored not in the same folder with script but in the new created folder, i already make that new folder currnt working folder but the result is still the same

Comment: Well give the code that you are using. Like I said, I can't help if I can;t reproduce it. The code you have above does not produce the error. You should be including the exact code that produces the error.

Comment: i've edited the code, so i want to create sub folder in the parent directory where the script is located, and store all the downloaded file into that sub folder

Answer (score 0):

**You may need to run your program as admin**
[Terminal opening python with sudo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60969.png)

**You likely need to run it as an admin as the code seems to be using the C:/ directory further more i think you should take out the username in the file path and edit this discussion**

Happy time coding

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a folder in the current working directory (where the py file is located), then hard coding the change directory. If you current working directory is not in the Users..\Documents, the the folder you created will not be there.

There's no need to change the current working directory. Just code the path of where you want the data stored.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


outputPath = r"C:\Users\EVOSYS\Documents\PROJECT-ISPU-DKI-JAKARTA-main\Project Data ISPU SPKU DKI JAKARTA 2010 - 2021"
os.makedirs(outputPath, exist_ok=True)


URLS = [
        'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2020',
        'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/indeks-standar-pencemaran-udara-ispu-tahun-2021',
        'https://data.jakarta.go.id/dataset/data-indeks-standar-pencemar-udara-ispu-di-provinsi-dki-jakarta-tahun-2019'
       ]


for url in URLS:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

    folder = url.split("/")[-1]
    folder = os.path.join(outputPath, folder)
    os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)

    for a in soup.select('a[href$=".csv"]'):
        file_name = a["href"].split("/")[-1]
        
        path = os.path.join(folder, file_name)

        print(
            "Downloading {} ...".format(path),
            end=" ",)
        
        with open(path, "wb") as f_out:
            f_out.write(requests.get(a["href"]).content)
        print("OK.")
```